# jQuery hide/show doesn't seem to work - am I doing something wrong

Tags: jquery, css, button, click

I am trying to show an element (which is a table, but I am using it as a div) when a submit button is clicked.

It doesn't seem to work. And I don't think that's because of bad CSS Karma acquired by using tables for layout.

Code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#object-created-panel").hide();                      
    $("#create-object-btn").click(
    function() { 
        $("#object-created-panel").show(""); 
        } 
    );      
});
```

Hopefully that is enough code to show what the error is (if not I will put in the code for the tables as well) the Submit button's id is: create-object-btn

Comment: I have figured out the problem. The showing and hiding is working fine. But what happens is that when the submit button is clicked the page reloads. Which is why I am not getting an error, but the object-created-panel is then hidden again. I will try to find how to prevent the reload, but if you know please let me know.

Comment: It was reloading because I had the submit button within <form> tags ... kind of a silly question in the end, but thanks for your help +1 for all answers

Answer (score 3):

Three steps:

1. Try to change show("") to show()
2. Check the selector work correct e.g. no object id 'object-created-panel'
3. Use Firebug to detect the javascript error

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 2):

Add the code "return false;" at the end of the click function to stop the page from posting back on this action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#object-created-panel").hide();                                          
    $("#create-object-btn").click(
        function() { 
            $("#object-created-panel").show("");
            return false;
        } 
    );          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `show("")` instead of `show()`?

[jQuery documentation on show()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show)

Comment: No particular reason. It's the result of copy/pasting, but that doesn't actually make a difference. Just checked it.

Comment: What are the css-properties applied on the 'object-created-panel'?